# How to publish python code to blog?

Tags: python, html, eclipse, blogger, code-snippets

*Is there a way to publish Python code into a blog?*

For instance, are there any plugins for Eclipse or Emacs that can be used to format or transform the code into HTML snippets for blogger?

I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515390/format-eclipse-code-snippets-for-blog-publishing) but there is no reference to Python and i was wondering if this is doable and how.

There is [this](http://codeformatter.blogspot.gr/2009/06/about-code-formatter.html) on-line source code formatter for blogger though i am not sure if it highlights python code properly..

any thoughts?

Appreciate all the good help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you try pygments  ?

http://pygments.org/

### Steps

1. Start your shell ( cmd if you are on windows)
2. Run : 'easy_install pygments' and wait

**You can use this**

```
pygmentize -f html -O full -o file.html file.py
```

-O full tells pygmentize to generate a complete HTML document

-o tells pygmentize to output the HTMl code to file.html

Comment: It is alright now. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IPython notebook has a utility for this: [nbconvert](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.0.0/interactive/nbconvert.html)

Comment: i am not familiar with ipython but i will look it up